# When trying to do a discord bot with a kick and ban feature this happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is one of my first bots, but when trying to do the command to ban someone in my discord bot it doesn't work.

log:

```
C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\index.js:570
    }else if(command = 'kick'){
                     ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\index.js:570:22)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:489:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\jason\Documents\jeffreys discord bot server spam\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

I was expecting it to work and would kick a test account. But instead I have this error message.

code fore the kick part
'''
if(command == 'clear') { client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args); }else if(command == 'kick'){ client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args); }else if(command == 'ban') client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
'''

Comment: Add your code. We can't help you if you don't.

Comment: The error is very straightforward, if you do not understand I highly suggest you learn JavaScript before working with a JavaScript library. You cannot reassign a variable that is declared with `const`

Comment: Did you mean `if (command == kick)`, testing and not assigning?

Comment: if(command == 'clear') {
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command == 'kick'){
    client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args); }else if(command == 'ban')
    client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
the code if you need it

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from your comparison operators. As mentioned in the comments:

> The error is very straightforward, if you do not understand I highly suggest you learn JavaScript before working with a JavaScript library. You cannot reassign a variable that is declared with `const`

##### `=` vs `==`

I will explain the different operators below. I believe you have used `=` instead of `==`. The single **`=`** assigns a value. For example

```js
const FooBar = 'HelloWorld'
```

Where as the `==` compares the values and will return a boolean (to trigger a IF, IF ELSE statement).

```js
FooBar == 'HelloWorld' => true
```

##### Comparisons

`==` means equal to

`!=` means NOT equal to

`>` means greater than

`>=` means greater than or equal to

`<` means less than

`<=` means less than or equal to